# Django form doesn't validate when init ModelMultipleChoiceField without data

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-select2

I want to use `ModelMultipleChoiceField` with `select2` in my `Django` application.

this is `forms.py` :

```
#forms.py
class SymbolForm(forms.Form):
    symbol = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Symbol.objects.all(), label='symbol')
```

Everything is ok except one thing. `Symbol` table has about 5 thousand record and when html rendered all data pass to html template. I don't want it.

I did change my form to this:

```
# forms.py
class SymbolForm(forms.Form):
    symbol = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Symbol.objects.all(), label='symbol')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SymbolForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['symbol'].queryset = Symbol.objects.none()
```

to init form without any data. **A new problem arises**: when form submitted, it is n't valid and django says that my chosen symbol doesn't valid choice.

**In fact, my problem is that I want to create the form without the data and then be able to verify it with the data I get from the `select2`, but Django does not allow this.**

***What can I do?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181253/select-a-valid-choice-that-choice-is-not-one-of-the-available-choices) question and [Sergio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6833205/sergio) answer, I found out that I need to rewrite init method of form:

```
self.fields['symbol'].queryset = Symbol.objects.none()
if 'symbol' in self.data:
    try:
        symbols_ids_list = list(map(int,  self.data.getlist('symbol')))
        self.fields['symbol'].queryset = Symbol.objects.filter(pk__in=symbols_ids_list).order_by()
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        pass
```